# How many things i need to save in onSaveInstanceState() method?

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I have 2 `Activities` 1 for the main menu and another for game window.

The problem is when the home button of the cellphone is pushed the pretest "game window" `Activity` goes to `onStop()` method, at this point all OK, but when I return to my app it crashes.

I have researched the problem and I think it was related to save the state of the mplayer object because of what the log said, I tried to save the state of the mplayer object but the app still have the same problem.

Do I need to save all my variables of the test view then? I appreciate the help.

The code of the second Activity

```
public class pretest extends Activity {
 private MediaPlayer mplayer;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,WindowManager.Layou        tParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
Toast.makeText(this, "onCreate2", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
if(mplayer!=null){mplayer.release();}

  mplayer=MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.forest);

View test = new test(this);
 mplayer.seekTo(0);
 mplayer.setLooping(true);
 mplayer.start();

  setContentView(test);  
    }

       @Override
     public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
         mostrarSalir();
         return true;
  }
   return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}


      @Override
  public void onStart(){
 super.onStart();

 Toast.makeText(this, "onStart2", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
       }

  @Override
    public void onStop(){
 super.onStop();

 Toast.makeText(this, "onStop2", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
          }

  @Override
  public void onRestart(){
 super.onRestart();

 Toast.makeText(this, "onRestart2", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
   public void onDestroy(){
 super.onDestroy();

 Toast.makeText(this, "onDestroy2", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
  }



@Override
    public void onPause(){
 super.onPause();
 Toast.makeText(this, "onPause2", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
 //LIBERA A MEDIA PLAYER
 if(mplayer!=null){mplayer.release();}

     }

    private void mostrarSalir(){
   AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

   dialog.setMessage("¿Desea Regresar al menu principal?");
   dialog.setCancelable(false);
   dialog.setPositiveButton("Si", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

   @Override
   public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {


       finish();



   }
     }); 
  dialog.setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

   @Override
   public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {


     Toast toast1 =
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            ":D!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);

                toast1.show();

     dialog.cancel();

   }
 });
  dialog.show();
 } 

  @Override
  public void onResume(){


 super.onResume();
 //reinicia
 Toast.makeText(this, "onResume2", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
 mplayer.seekTo(0);
   mplayer.start();

  }

   @Override
   protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle estadoguardado){

 super.onSaveInstanceState(estadoguardado);
 if(mplayer!=null){

     int pos=mplayer.getCurrentPosition();
     estadoguardado.putInt("posicion", pos); 
 } 

  }

   @Override    
   protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle estadoguardado)
   {

  super.onRestoreInstanceState(estadoguardado);


 if(estadoguardado!=null&&mplayer!=null){
 int pos=estadoguardado.getInt("posicion");
 mplayer.seekTo(pos);

       }

     }

   }
```

The Error log:

```
  05-08 02:55:32.036: E/AndroidRuntime(7904): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
  05-08 02:55:32.036: E/AndroidRuntime(7904): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to       resume activity {com.example.brain/com.example.brain.pretest}:                                java.lang.IllegalStateException
    05-08 02:55:32.036: E/AndroidRuntime(7904):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2214)
 05-08 02:55:32.036: E/AndroidRuntime(7904):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2229)
 05-08 02:55:32.036: E/AndroidRuntime(7904):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1019)
 05-08 02:55:32.036: E/AndroidRuntime(7904):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:130)
 05-08 02:55:32.036: E/AndroidRuntime(7904):    at android.os.Looper.loop(SourceFile:351)
 05-08 02:55:32.036: E/AndroidRuntime(7904):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3814)
 05-08 02:55:32.036: E/AndroidRuntime(7904):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
 05-08 02:55:32.036: E/AndroidRuntime(7904):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:538)
 05-08 02:55:32.036: E/AndroidRuntime(7904):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:901)
 05-08 02:55:32.036: E/AndroidRuntime(7904):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:659)
  05-08 02:55:32.036: E/AndroidRuntime(7904):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 05-08 02:55:32.036: E/AndroidRuntime(7904): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException
 05-08 02:55:32.036: E/AndroidRuntime(7904):    at android.media.MediaPlayer.seekTo(Native Method)
  05-08 02:55:32.036: E/AndroidRuntime(7904):   at com.example.brain.pretest.onResume(pretest.java:135)
  05-08 02:55:32.036: E/AndroidRuntime(7904):   at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnResume(Instrumentation.java:1189)
   05-08 02:55:32.036: E/AndroidRuntime(7904):  at android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:3896)
  05-08 02:55:32.036: E/AndroidRuntime(7904):   at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2204)
 05-08 02:55:32.036: E/AndroidRuntime(7904):    ... 10 more
```

Comment: When onPause is called, you're releasing the resources held by the MediaPlayer instance, and when you come back to the app later, you're trying to call the seekTo method on the old instance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your onPause you are releasing the `MediaPlayer`. This well let go of any resources it was linked to in the sub system.

This should be like:

```
@Override
public void onPause()
{
    super.onPause();
    Toast.makeText(this, "onPause2", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    //LIBERA A MEDIA PLAYER
    if (mplayer != null)
    {
        mplayer.release();
        mplayer = null;
    }

}
```

But change your resume to:

```
@Override
public void onResume()
{


    super.onResume();
    //reinicia
    Toast.makeText(this, "onResume2", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    if (mplayer == null)
        mplayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.forest);
    mplayer.seekTo(0);
    mplayer.setLooping(true);
    mplayer.start();
}
```

You can tweak this a bit more, as you should actually `release` in the `onStop` and create in the `onStart`.

Then you `pause` in `onPause` and `play` in the `onStart` that way you keep the reference to the unless you actually leave the app. should make going backwards and forwards a bit smoother.

Comment: Thanks! ,one last question, so the protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle estadoguardado) method is only used when the activity call the onDestroy method?

Comment: Yeah its called before `onDestroy` from my memory. And `onRestore` is called after `onCreate`.